# List view control drawn incorrectly when groups are present

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe2

I was experimenting with list view groups, and it turns out the control displays incorrectly when the application starts.

[image: Original form]

As soon as I resize the form it displays correctly:

[image: Resized form]

I do not understand what is happening. Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug in the Delphi control which I have reproduced. I'm not sure yet what causes the bug. I have submitted this to Quality Central as [QC#101104](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=101104).

I found a simple workaround by adding the following code to the form's `OnShow` event.

```
ListView1.Align := alNone;
ListView1.Align := alClient;
```

---

The following DFM file is enough to demonstrate the problem:

```
object MyForm: TMyForm
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  ClientHeight = 300
  ClientWidth = 635
  object ListView1: TListView
    Left = 200
    Top = 96
    Width = 250
    Height = 150
    Align = alClient
    Columns = <
      item
        Caption = 'Column'
      end>
    Groups = <
      item
        Header = 'Group header'
        GroupID = 0
      end>
    Items.ItemData = {
      052A0000000100000000000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0000000000000000000000
      000854006800650020006900740065006D00}
    GroupView = True
    ViewStyle = vsReport
  end
end
```

It turns out that another way to resolve the problem is to move the `ViewStyle` entry in the DFM file so that it appears before the `Items` entry. So yet another workaround for the problem would be to add the items at runtime. In fact this probably explains why this bug has not been found since I bet that the overwhelming majority of list view code adds the items at runtime.

Comment: @jhon does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!, I erased the previous answer thank you haha